# EC2 ASG instance fails to report successful status

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm currently trying to bring up a server in an autoscaling group with a custom init script. The init script is failing on the server, which is causing the Autoscaling group not to come up. Tailing the logs on the server ends with:

```
Cloud-init v. 22.3.4-0ubuntu1~20.04.1 running 'modules:final' at Thu, 17 Nov 2022 21:02:38 +0000. Up 53.27 seconds.
2022-11-17 21:05:42,663 - cc_scripts_user.py[WARNING]: Failed to run module scripts-user (scripts in /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts)
2022-11-17 21:05:42,664 - util.py[WARNING]: Running module scripts-user (<module 'cloudinit.config.cc_scripts_user' from '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/config/cc_scripts_user.py'>) failed
```

My Cloudformation template:

```
WebLaunchConfig:
  Type: AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration
  Properties:
    BlockDeviceMappings:
      - DeviceName: /dev/sda1
        Ebs:
          VolumeSize: 100
          VolumeType: gp2
    KeyName: devteam
    IamInstanceProfile: {Ref: WebInstanceProfile}
    ImageId: {Ref: AMI}
    InstanceType: {Ref: InstanceType}
    SecurityGroups: {Ref: WebSecurityGroups}
    UserData:
      Fn::Base64:
        !Sub |
          #!/bin/bash -ex
          full_hostname="${AWS::StackName}-$(ec2metadata --instance-id).itglue.com"
          echo $full_hostname > /etc/hostname
          hostname $full_hostname
          echo "$(ec2metadata --local-ipv4) ${!full_hostname}" >> /etc/hosts
          service rsyslog restart

          sed -i "s/environment = qa/environment = ${PuppetEnv}/" /etc/puppet/puppet.conf
          set +e

          puppet agent --enable
          service puppet stop || true
          while [[ -e /var/lib/puppet/state/agent_catalog_run.lock ]]; do
            echo "Waiting for puppet run to finish"
            sleep 10
          done

          puppet agent -t
          puppet_ret=$?
          echo $puppet_ret
          # Puppet agent error code docs under '--detailed-exitcodes': https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/man/agent.html
          if [ $puppet_ret -eq 1 ] || [ $puppet_ret -eq 4 ] || [ $puppet_ret -eq 6 ]
          then
            echo "Puppet run failed!"
            exit 1
          fi
          set -e
          service puppet start

          {% if not sceptre_user_data.get('personal_env', false) %}
          service webapp stop; sleep 5 && service webapp start
          RAILS_ENV=${RailsEnv} /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm in /var/www/webapp/current do bundle exec rake smoke_test:run
          {% endif %}

          # for hostname logging rename to take effect:
          service amazon-cloudwatch-agent restart

          test -d /var/www/webapp/current/vendor/ruby/${RubyMajorVersion}

          /usr/local/bin/cfn-signal -s true --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource WebAutoScaleGroup --region ${AWS::Region}
```

Currently I can't figure out why the `cfn-signal` command isn't running.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ah, you're using [cfn-signal - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-signal.html)! It is always difficult to debug. I'd recommend adding lots of debugging code into the script to identify exactly where it has progressed and what values it is passing to `cfn-signal`. You can then look in the User Data log (`/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`) as long as the instance hasn't been deleted. That should help you identify where the script is getting stuck.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein right now, everything seems to run up until the `cfn-signal` command.

Comment: Does your EC2 instance have connectivity with the Internet? For example, is it in a public subnet with a Public IP address, or is it in a private subnet with a NAT Gateway providing connectivity to the Internet? Such access is required to 'signal back' to CloudFormation that the User Data script has finished running.

Comment: FYI, one test you can perform is to `echo` the values that are being sent in the `cfn-signal` command so that they appear in the log file. Login to the instance and view the log file, then **manually issue the `cfn-signal` command** on the command-line. That will confirm whether the values are correct and whether the `cfn-signal` command is correctly running.